# How do you create a UIMenuController for something that is not text-based?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uimenucontroller

Apple's Messages app, as well as many other third party apps support a `UIMenuController` style popover for selecting messages.

[image]

However, in browsing [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html) it seems that it's only used for text related selection.

Is it possible to extend it to other `UIViews`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the tableView delegate API:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath withSender:(id)sender;
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath withSender:(id)sender;
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
```

Beyond that, the `canPerformAction:` responder API can be used to support actions, but you will be responsible for displaying the menu using `UIMenuController`.